# How can I get element ID on new window using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have this PHP:

```
echo'
<a href="?model='.$f_sek['model'].'&id='.$f_sek['id'].'" class="open_div">
<img src="images/model/'.$f_sek['model'].'.png">
</a>';
```

When I click on the image, it opens a JQuery UI window:

```
$("#new_div").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

$(".open_div").click(
    function () {
        $("#new_div").dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
);
```

I just want send `$_GET[id]` to `new_div`. I mean when the new window opened I can see `$_GET[id]` which I clicked.

P.S I can write HTML FORM of `#new_div`, but I think that is not important.

Comment: You forgot `echo` there somewhere?

Comment: `dialog` is not a `new window`...it is just overlayed `DIV` and has nothing to do with browser `window`

Comment: Cause u have not jquery Ui scripts, imagine that this is a new vindow

Comment: check it:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: no...there is a huge difference between using an in page widget like dialog and `new window` which is part of browser... do web search for `window.open(url)` and then try running it with a valid url as argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you may want to consider a function and pass your arguments that way (make sure your php variables are quoted if they're strings):

```
echo'
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.myOpenDialog('.$f_sek['model'].','.$f_sek['id'].')">
<img src="images/model/'.$f_sek['model'].'.png">
</a>';
```

Then, the function could open the dialog after loading content into it based on your arguments:

```
$.myOpenDialog = function(model,id) {
   var url = "/?model="+model+"&id="+id;
   $("#new_div").load(url).dialog('open');
}
```